# how to connect mysql database to laravel in ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, ubuntu

I am new bee in laravel. I am using ubuntu terminal. I have installed laravel and created one database and one table using terminal. Now i want to connect that database with my laravel project. I have changed database name, username and password in app/config/database.php. But don't know the connection is establish or not.

**In database.php i have changed in mysql array:**

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'prac',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'admin',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

When i fetch the data from table it display pdoexception could not find drivers. I want connection with mysql.

Comment: install php5-mysql i.e. `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` for php5.x

Comment: i think i need to install pdo driver ???

Comment: @chetan sir I have tried this but same error..

Comment: yes `php5-mysql` or `php-mysql` will install the dependencies also

Comment: after installation you need to restart apache server

Comment: woww.... thanks sir now it is working....

Comment: one more que. that do i need to install every time when i start new project or just once i installed it will work every time ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94471/discussion-between-chetan-ameta-and-deep-parekh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"pdoexception could not find drivers" this error seems to be you don't have php mysql extension installed in your machine

Check is it installed ? using this command `dpkg --list | grep php5-mysql` 
If this command give nothing then you don't have php5-mysql extension. You can install it using following command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

after that you have to restart your apache server for load the new extension

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Quick note: use `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` if you want the latest version (in my case, `php7.1`)